# object does not contain a definition for "SaveChanges"

Tags: c#

I got an error and it's so nerve-wracking ... I added a partial class to my project and put SaveChangeExeptionEntities for it's name...

I got this error:

> object does not contain a definition for "SaveChanges"

and here is code :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
   public partial class SaveChangeExeptionEntities
    {
       public override int SaveChanges()
       {
           try
           {
               return base.SaveChanges();
           }
           catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
           {
               // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
               var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                       .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                       .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

               // Join the list to a single string.
               var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

               // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
               var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

               // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
               throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

pls help me! I'm going to crazy :(

Comment: Well is there another `SaveChangeExeptionEntities` partial class declared elsewhere? What do you expect this class to derive from? Perhaps it's just a typo and your other class is correctly named `SaveChangeExceptionEntities`? (Note the c in Exception.)

Comment: @Jon-Skeet I have a class, it's name is "BuyForm.cs" .. in this class I have my main code and an entity conncetor to database table .. I had to handle an exeption fo SaveChange object... I add this exeption to a partial class... and I got this error... I'm newbie in C# and I worked on Java before...

Comment: If you're new to C#, I'd suggest starting with things that are slightly simpler - it's really unclear whether you've got another "part" to this partial class, or whether you've just made up the name from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a partial class that is not inheriting from nothing..you can't do `base.SaveChanges();` since you have not a base

here's some info for the partial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.110).aspx

and here the base call (you can see the inheritance)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx

An example of partial class:

```
public partial class CoOrds
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public CoOrds(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public partial class CoOrds
{
    public void PrintCoOrds()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CoOrds: {0},{1}", x, y);
    }

}

class TestCoOrds
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CoOrds myCoOrds = new CoOrds(10, 15);
        myCoOrds.PrintCoOrds();

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

you can see that the object myCoOrds is implemented with the costructor that is written in the first part of the partial and use the method written in the second part of the partial class...hope it helps to understand better

Comment: can I inherit it from my main class ?

Comment: (see my edits) and read some documentation after that yes if you have a main class that have a method called SaveChanges you can declare your class like that:
public class SaveChangeExeptionEntities: MainClass 
and then call the base.SaveChanges

Comment: This code would be okay if there were another declaration of the same partial class with an appropriate base class.

Comment: I inherit it from my entity database:     public partial class SaveChangeExeptionEntities : notebookEntities ... and it's now okay! Thank u !

Comment: i'm glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

base here refers to System.Windows.Forms.Form, and you are inheriting that. Form doesn't have any SaveChanges call, EF has. You just need to wrap up the save changes call in Try Catch block.

And you are using Partial Class in some confusion here.

You can do something like this also

```
public class ExtendedClass : BaseEFClassForMyEntity
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (exception ex) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now create instance of `ExtendedClass` and that is done

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using entity framework!! you have to write this method in your DbContext class.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
   {
       try
       {
           return base.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
       {
           // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
           var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                   .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                   .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

           // Join the list to a single string.
           var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

           // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
           var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

           // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
           throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
       }
   }

}
```